# Unable to import spring configuration class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have  springbootapplication as below

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MyApp{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
      SpringApplication s = new SpringApplication(Config.class)
s.run(args)
    }

} 
@Configuration
@import({SampleConfig.class})
class Config{
}
```

SampleConfig.class is a spring configuartion class in other project which i have imported in above pom.

SampleConfig class is follow

```
@Configuration
class SampleConfig{
@Bean
public XYZ xyz(){
return new XYZ()
}
```

But for some reason SampleConfig class is not imported and i am unable to use XYZ

Comment: Do you have the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on your `MyApp` class?

Comment: what are you doing in Config class and what is the error???

Comment: There is no error. I have a sys out in postConstuct defindd in XYZ class . Sysout is not printed

Comment: Can you share all of the code that’s involved, including package declarations and import statements?